# Printing a big integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, printing, integer, biginteger

I am experimenting with a JavaScript library for working with big integers called [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js).

Specifically, I am trying to print a big integer. However, I am getting puzzling results. For instance, when I try this:

```
var x= bigInt("53542885039854749852");
document.write(x+"<br>");
```

...I am getting `53542885039854750000`. And when I try this:

```
var x= bigInt("104156103156113102156118165104101120101");
document.write(x+"<br>");
```

...the result is `1.041561031561131e+38`.

Can someone help me understand why I am not getting the results I expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`toString()`](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js#override-methods) method to get a string with all digits.

> **Note that arithmetical operators will trigger the  `valueOf` function rather than the `toString` function.** When converting a bigInteger to a string, you should use the  toString  method or the  String  function instead of adding the empty string.
>
> - `bigInt("999999999999999999").toString()  =>  "999999999999999999"`
> - `String(bigInt("999999999999999999"))  =>  "999999999999999999"`
> - `bigInt("999999999999999999") + ""  =>  1000000000000000000`

```js
var x= bigInt("53542885039854749852");
document.write(x + "<br>");             // this calls valueOf
document.write(x.valueOf() + "<br>");
document.write(x.toString() + "<br>");
```

```html
<script src="http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

To calculate something, you could use the methods of the class.

```js
   
var y = bigInt("104156103156113102156118165104101120101");
document.write(y.plus(1).toString() + "<br>");
document.write(y.multiply(2).toString() + "<br>");
document.write(y.plus(y).toString() + "<br>");
```

```html
<script src="http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```